# How do I prove that the matrix $A^{-1}=CD^{-1}C^{-1}?$

Tags: linear-algebra

> How do I prove that the matrix $A^{-1}=CD^{-1}C^{-1}?$

Where we define  $D$ as the diagonal matrix and $C$ is constructed of the eigenvectors.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you can first prove that $A=CDC^{-1}$, then you just invert both sides and you are done.  As for what $A$ you are able to write in this form and why, read your book or wikipedia about [diagonalizable matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix).  There are surely entire chapters devoted to the subject in any linear algebra text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand how to prove $A = CDC^{-1}$ from $D =   C^{-1}AC$. But if I invert $A = CDC^{-1}$ on both sides I get $A^{-1} = C^{-1}D^{-1}C$. It gives the same result as  $A^{-1} = CD^{-1}C^{-1}$, I just do not see how to convert it to this form. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First things first: do you know how to prove $(\mathbf A\mathbf B)^{-1}=\mathbf B^{-1}\mathbf A^{-1}$?

Comment: That is what I missed! Thank you @J.M.isnotamathematician! This way I can calculate $(CDC^{-1})^{-1} = CD^{-1}C^{-1}$ from $(CDC^{-1})(CDC^{-1})^{-1} = I$.

Comment: If you've figured it out, please write an answer to your own question. :)